# $L^p$ space inequality

Tags: inequality, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Let $\mu$ be a positive measure, $f,g \in L^p(\mu)$,$ \parallel f\parallel _p \leq R$, $ \parallel g \parallel _ p \leq R$

I have to prove :

$$\int ||f|^p-|g|^p|d\mu \leq 2pR^{p-1} \parallel f-g\parallel _p$$

for $ p>1$.

I was given a hint , that says that, for $x,y \geq 0$ ,

$$|x^p-y^p| \leq p |x-y|(x^{p-1}+y^{p-1})$$

I have been trying to do it, it seems easy with the hint, but I can't find a way to do it.

Applying the last inequality :

$||f|^p-|g|^p| \leq p|f-g|(|f|^{p-1} +|g|^{p-1})$

Integrating both sides:

$\int ||f|^p-|g|^p|d\mu \leq p\int|f-g|(|f|^{p-1} +|g|^{p-1}) d \mu$

but I can't see how I can get from there to the result. I think I have to use some kind of inequality like Minkowski's.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Hello, is that $p>1$ or $0<p<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If $p>1$:**

By Holder's inequality,
\begin{align*}
\int\bigg||f|^{p}-|g|^{p}\bigg|\leq p\|f-g\|_{L^{p}}\left(\int(|f|^{p-1}+|g|^{p-1})^{q}\right)^{1/q},
\end{align*}
where $1/p+1/q=1$. But we also have $(a+b)^{q}\leq 2^{q-1}(a^{q}+b^{q})$ for $a,b\geq 0$, so
\begin{align*}
\left(\int(|f|^{p-1}+|g|^{p-1})^{q}\right)^{1/q}&\leq 2^{(q-1)/q}\left(\int|f|^{(p-1)q}+|g|^{(p-1)q}\right)^{1/q}\\
&=2^{1/p}\left(\int|f|^{p}+|g|^{p}\right)^{1/q}\\
&\leq 2^{1/p}(\|f\|_{L^{p}}^{p}+\|g\|_{L^{p}}^{p})^{1/q}\\
&=2^{1/p}2^{1/q} R^{p/q}\\
&=2 R^{p-1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: There is no Hölder inequality for $p < 1$. I am not sure, however, if this is really what the OP wanted.

Comment: It is weird that for $p>1$, the result is exactly like that. So maybe OP made a typo?